# Adding and removing buttons in ForEach view

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
                        ForEach(StaffList, id: \.self) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(item)")
                                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                                    Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            //TODO: Remove user UUID from array + Show add button
                                        }
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            //TODO: Add user UUID from array + Show remove button
                                        }
                            }
                        }
```

A simple solution would be one @state variable in the Struct for every one in the loop, but it arises a problem. Because each button is assigned to the same variable. When the variable changes, all of them change. For example:

```
@State var isShowing = false


                        ForEach(StaffList, id: \.self) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(item)")
                                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                                if isShowing {
                                    Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            //TODO: Remove user UUID from array + Show add button
                                            is Showing = true
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            //TODO: Add user UUID from array + Show remove button
                                            isShowing = false
                                        }
                                 }
                            }
                        }
```

Technically this works, but take into consideration the unlimited amount of people in `StaffList`. If I click `X` on one of them, they would all update to show a `Checkmark`. The goal is ForEach, they all have their own set of changes if that makes since. So when I click `X` on one of them, it updates and shows the `Checkmark` but none of the others in the ForEach loop update, and still show the `X`.

Comment: I can't understand: your buttons are not showing with the above code?

Comment: No, they are showing, I'd like a way to hide the checkmark until the X is clicked. I'd also like it to hide the X when clicked so only one of the buttons is showing at one time.

Basically, one button should only be shown at one time. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
*After the latest update in the question, here's the corrected answer to address the issue "Buttons are changing for all items rather than for each single item"*

You can hide or show the buttons using an `@State` variable. There are several tutorials online.

But to change the buttons for each single member of `StaffList` separately (which we'd better call `staffList` since it's a variable), you need to have one `@State` variable for each item in the `ForEach`. This can be achieved by creating a secondary view, which in the example below I called `ItemView`.

Here's the code:

```
struct YourMainView: View {
    // This is not the right place for the @State variable that affects each single item
    // @State var isShowing = false

    // Other variable declarations

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(staffList, id: \.self) { item in
            ItemView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

// This is the view of each single item
struct ItemView: View {

    let item: StaffListItemType    // Whatever the actual type is

    // Here is the right place to manage it (always make it private)
    @State private var isShowing = false

    var body: some View {
            HStack {
               Text("\(item)")
               Spacer(minLength: 0)
               if isShowing {
                    Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            //TODO: Remove user UUID from array + Show add button
                            isShowing = false  // If it's true, it needs to become false. Or, use .toggle()
                         }
               } else {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                             //TODO: Add user UUID from array + Show remove button
                             isShowing = true  // If it's false, it needs to become true. Or, use .toggle()
                         }
               }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same answer I came up with. Problem is, if you ran it, wouldn't all the circles change, when I only tap one in the ForEach loop.

Comment: @user17864647: sorry, I guess I didn't understand the question then. What do you mean by "wouldn't all the circles change, when I only tap one in the ForEach loop"? Don't you want to hide one and show only the other one? Or you want them both to be shown together? Can you provide in your question a simple example of what you want to achieve? If I can help you, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but how can I quickly toggle on all the toggles in the Foreach statement without exiting the view and going back in?

Comment: @user17864647: I'm not sure I understand your last question, do you want to toggle all the items in the list at the same time? Or is there some kind of bug that does not update the view? I suggest you open a new question, so other people can jump in too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71623801/17864647